# Перенести php код в шаблонизатор Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Есть php код который нужно вывести в smarty, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, вот код:

```
               <option id="marka-avto">Выберите марку авто</option>
                        <?php
                            //Выводим категории и ее ID
                            while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                            $marka = $row['marka']; 
                            echo "<option value=\"$marka\">$marka</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

Этот код нужно перенести в шаблнизатор.

```
       {
    $sqlmy->query('SELECT DISTINCT marka FROM filtr_db');       
    $result = mysql_query($sqlmy);
        //Выводим категории и ее ID
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
        {
        $marka = $row['marka']; 
        echo "<option value=\"$marka\">$marka</option>";
        }

    }
```

если делать так то передается просто $marka а не значения из бд

Comment: А вы документацию читали? https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: Просто хочу понять почему не работает, может есть тут знающие

Comment: Зачем читать доки, когда можно тут спросить, да?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Answer (score 1):

Отделение "представления (хтмл)" от логики (пхп кода) это весьма хорошо, и шаблонизаторы здесь весьма упрощают нам жизнь. Однако не стоит тащить в шаблон все, что плохо лежит. Ваша задача в пхп коде подготовить данные, и передать их в шаблон. Таким образом в пхп коде должна быть написана вся логика по выборке данных из БД, а результат передан в шаблон.

То есть в пхп файле у вас остается?

```
$query = "select ... ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $options[] = $row; 
}

$smarty->assign('options', $options);
$smarty->assign('current', $current); // выбранный пункт
```

А в tpl-шаблоне вы только выводите уже сформированные данные:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option id="" value="">Выберите марку авто</option>
    {foreach $options as $o}
    <option value="{$o.marka}" {if $o.marka == $current}selected{/if}>{$o.marka}    </option> 
    {/foreach} 
</select>
```

если вы будете пытаться в переносить работу с БД в шаблон, то лучше просто не используйте шаблоны.

Также обратите внимание, что более свежие версии пхп (7.х) гораздо эффективнее, а расширение `mysql_` устарело еще лет 10 назад, и собственно в пхп 7 его уже и нет. Используйте PDO:

```
$sth = $pdo->query('select...');
$options = $sth->fetchAll();
```